# How to get a specific Value from an array with forEach

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests. How do I do this?

Im bound to use pure JS, and i'm realy new to it (like realy realy new). So please excuse my noob question. :)

My array looks like this :

```
var questionArr = [
    {
        'questionId' : 'Question1',
        'question' : 'Q1: How many Objects are there? ',
        'choices' : [
            {"id" : "10", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "11", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "12", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "15", "tf" : true, "points" : 10},
            {'id' : "16", "tf" : false, "points" : 0}
        ],
        'Mchoice' : false,
        'completed' : false
    },
    {
        'questionId' : 'Question2',
        'question' : 'Q2: some Question will go here? ',
        'choices' : [
```

and ongoing.

Its for a quiz as you can see, and i want to get the Value of 'completed'. Im changing the value into true later on to check if a question has been answered or not. If there is at least on answer for every question selected, a submit button should be enabled.

So i was thinking about using a forEach loop to check if completed is set to true or false for every question.

My forEach looks like this, at least it does so far.

```
questionArr.forEach(function(questionId, value){
 console.log(questionId, value);
});
```

I'm realy clueless how i'm supposed to check for that value now and how i than proceed from there to enable my button. For the button i was think about something like this, this is more an optional question now, but it would be good to know if i'm going in the right direction with this.

```
for(l = 0; l < questionArr[questionId].completed ; l++){
        if (questionArr[l].completed === true){
            button = document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, there are two ways to achieve this.

Using forEach, the best way would be to do this:

```
var allComplete = true;
questionArr.forEach(function(question, index) {
    if(!question.completed)
        allComplete = false;
});

// enable/disable your button based on the value of allComplete
```

You're passing a function to `forEach` which is called for every element in the array. That function can take up to three arguments: the current element, the index of that element, and the array that `forEach` is being called on. We're only really interested in the element itself, so I could have gotten away with only declaring that in the function signature. I've given the element's parameter the name `question`, because that's what it refers to; the reason for calling the next one `index` should be obvious.

However, if it's supported by all the browsers you need to support, you could use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function on the Array prototype:

```
var allComplete = questionArr.every(function(question, index) {
    return question.completed;
});

// enable/disable your button based on the value of allComplete
```

Comment: Thank you, this realy helped me. @user1600124 I went with ur solution at first, but this simplyfies it for me so im going with Anthony's answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
    var num = 0,
        cnt = questionArr.length;
    questionArr.forEach(function(val, i, arr){
        if(val.completed) num++;
        if(num == cnt) document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.. but the function you gave to forEach is not correct.
The signature of the function should be like this:

```
questionArr.forEach(function (item, idx) {});
```

Where the item would be each item within questionArr, and idx is the index of the item in the array.

So you might end up with something like:

```
questionArr.forEach(function (item, idx) 
{
   if(!item.completed) 
   {
       alert(item.questionId);
   }
}
```

With some modifications you should get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all items in your array, and keep track of the completed status of all of them, if one of these is false, allCompleted will be false.

```
var allCompleted = true;

for(l = 0; l < questionArr.length ; l++){
  allCompleted = allCompleted && questionArr[l].completed;
}

if (allCompleted) {
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read object like:

```
// Here obj is current element and value is index of that element
questionArr.forEach(function(obj, value){   
     console.log(obj.questionId); 
     console.log(obj.question); 
     console.log(obj.Mchoice);
     console.log(obj.completed); 
 });
```

for

```
    'choices' : [
            {"id" : "10", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "11", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "12", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "15", "tf" : true, "points" : 10},
            {'id' : "16", "tf" : false, "points" : 0}
        ]
```

you need to use again forEach to find values in same fashion.